# Azure Linux Web Server didn't respond to my Docker container

Tags: node.js, azure, docker

Im trying to deploy my small node js application to azure web service via Azure container registry.

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the static files from the build directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// Serve the React app on all other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('BEGIN');
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

this is my Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Node.js 16.x image as the base image
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install express

COPY "./server.js" .
COPY "./packages/claim-management/build" "./build"

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I added both variables in the configuration for port exposing.

```
  WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT   = 400
  WEBSITES_PORT                         = 3000
```

and this is my logs from Azure:

```
2023-03-25T12:04:11.620Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container claim-management_0_cd4e268d_msiProxy for site claim-management
2023-03-25T12:04:11.633Z INFO  - Container claim-management_0_cd4e268d_msiProxy for site claim-management initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2023-03-25T12:04:11.634Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container claim-management_0_cd4e268d for site claim-management
2023-03-25T12:04:11.382860821Z exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
2023-03-25T12:04:26.892Z ERROR - Container claim-management_0_cd4e268d for site claim-management has exited, failing site start
2023-03-25T12:04:26.900Z ERROR - Container claim-management_0_cd4e268d didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2023-03-25T12:04:26.906Z INFO  - Stopping site claim-management because it failed during startup.
```

The container work locally, and I can run it via the command `docker run -p 3000:3000`, but what I can see Azure trying to start the container via `docker run -d --expose=3000. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you share the logs of the container as azure instructs?

Comment: Azure Web App for Containers runs on an ARM64 architecture. So, you need to use an image that's compatible with the ARM64 architecture.

You can try using the node:16-alpine3.14 image, which is compatible with the ARM64 architecture, instead of node:16-alpine

Comment: Thanks everyone, answer is almost which @alex suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it:
Just make sure that (if you are a mac m1 user or any other processor which is not compatible with Azure Web Services ) you added the platform to your Dockerfile:

```
# Need platform to much with your current extension
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY "./server.js" .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Make sure that you use WEBSITES_PORT variable in the Configuration section of you App Service and that it it match EXPOSE port from your Dockerfile!